# To prevent from entering the same links in the other pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my website, when you create a product page, you can upload files or add links.
To prevent from entering the same links in the **same product page**, there is this

```
validate :check_download_links_unique!

    def check_download_links_unique!
      urls = download_links.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).map!(&:url).compact.to_a
      errors.add(
        :download_links, :links_repetition
      ) if urls.uniq.length != urls.length
    end
```

Now I want to check also another thing. I want to prevent from entering the **same link** already added **in another product page**.

I tried to add in models/download_link.rb somethig like this

```
validates :url, uniqueness: true
```

But it blocks also the upload of **the files**. Any tips?

the models

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: download_links
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  url               :string
#  broken            :boolean          default(FALSE), not null
#  book_id           :integer
#  file_file_name    :string
#  file_content_type :string

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: books
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  title            :string           not null
#  slug             :string           not null
#  description      :text             not null
#  user_id          :integer
#  downloads_count  :integer          default(0), not null
```

Comment: Could you provide your models such as `Product` and `DownloadLink`?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because when you upload a file, `url` becomes `nil`, which is not permitted by default with `uniqueness: true`.

As the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) says, you must set `allow_nil: true` option to `uniqueness: true` in order to skip uniqueness validation when the attribute is `nil`.

---

If you want to guard from empty string, you can do something like this:

```rb
validates :url, format: {with: /\S+/}, uniqueness: true
```

Comment: but I can't do it. Because in this way the users can also add an empty space

Comment: But in this way the users can also add an empty space! Should I add an IF?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `allow_nil: true` to `uniqueness: true`, and strip the `url` before validation to prevent empty space url.